# WKWebView not running on device

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

my main issue is WKWebView....when i run my app its supposed to navigate to a website behind the scene and login the user by running a some code from a .js file found on the main bundle.

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

 //  Load username and password from NSUserDefults

        self.staffID = defaults.objectForKey("UserName") as String
        self.pass = defaults.objectForKey("PassWord") as String

    // locate file from main bundle
        let populateLoginURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("login", ofType: "js")       
// edit username and password
      var PassEdited = pass + "'"
        println(pass)
        var PassJs = "document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = '" + PassEdited
        var usernameEdited = "'" + staffID + "'"
        println(staffID)
        var userNameJS = "document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = " + usernameEdited
    // submit fuction will validate username and password on webpage
        let submit = "submitButton()"
    //combine the java code in one line
       let javaCode = userNameJS + "; " + PassJs + "; " + submit
    // write java code to file in main bundle which is empty
      javaCode.writeToFile(populateLoginURL!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    //configure webView
       self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    // load javacode to inject from file
        let populateLoginJS = String(contentsOfFile:populateLoginURL!,   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        let populateLoginScript = WKUserScript(source: populateLoginJS!,    injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
// add configuration to webview
        configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(populateLoginScript)

                       configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration:      configuration)

    println(populateLoginJS)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
//set navigation delegate of web view and navigate to specified url
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://ifly.etihad.ae")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:URL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
   }
```

this all works without a glitch on IOS simulator.

with that being said i have noticed the last println(populateLoginJs) usually prints the content of the .Js file however when run on my device it prints optional""

so either the writing to JS file is not working or the loading to JS file is not working That is my hunch

guys any ideas or info willl be highly appreciated

Comment: Why are you declaring your variables inside required init?

Comment: guys i managed to get the code to run however i found the issue to be the writeToFile is not working on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve the issue, i found out the write to file was never compiling on the device. after contacting apple support they said its a bug that they are aware of.

os the way i am handling the issue now is checking what URL the webView is on if true then webView.evaluateJavaScript